# Почему vertical-align подгоняет под себя родителя block?

Tags: html, css

Совершенно случайно для себя заметил странное для себя поведение блоков и строчных элементов/блоков. Если им выставить vertical-align: middle/top/bottom, то блок подгоняет свою высоту под инлайновых блок, а без этого он создает пустоту.
Почему такое поведение? У меня единственное предположение, что пустота создается из-за невидимых пробелов.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}

.div1 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.div1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x68/000000/fff" alt="">
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x68/000000/fff" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Причем если заменить vertical-align: middle; на display:block - результат аналогичен.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/51140/